# How to to run the substrate-node-template with parity-db instead of rockdb?

Tags: database, rocks-db

I'm looking for a how-to-guide, or an example that runs the `substrate-node-template` using `parity-db` instead of `rockdb`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to run the node with `--database paritydb` and that's it.

Comment: How about enabling these as default in the client without the node operator setting this flag?

Comment: I don't want to compile `rockdb` at all. Only use `parity-db`. Is that even possible? TIA.

Comment: Not compiling `rocksdb` is currently not possible. Would require some changes to the code.

Regarding enabling it by default, yes that will come when paritydb is seen as 100% stable.

Comment: Thanks @bkchr, I'll update the question so it becomes useful then.

Comment: @PabloBuitrago you could try compiling Substrate with only `parity-db`  using this commit https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13177#issuecomment-1465505579